# Conectar a base de datos Firebird a través de Data View en Genexus 10 evo 3

Tags: base-de-datos, genexus, firebird

Estoy probando diferentes maneras de conectarme a una base de datos externa Firebird desde un Data View de Genexus, pero no existe la opción del datastore Firebird. Lo he probado con otras opciones: SQL Server, DB2, MySQL,...pero nada, no consigo conectar. ¿Alguien conoce alguna forma de conectarse a esa base de datos con Genexus?

Gracias.

Eduard

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Firebird es un fork de la versión 6 de Interbase, que tenía licencia open source. Ya hace tiempo difirieron tanto que nadie se conecta más utilizando drivers de Interbase, pero si tienes alguno disponible, es probable que sea mejor que nada. Depende mucho de a qué versión de Firebird quieras conectarte y qué es lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: En una búsqueda rápida, me pareció ver que [Genexus usa drivers de JDBC](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?10391,JDBC+Driver+Property) (¿está hecho en java?). Si es así, puedes usar el driver oficial de Firebird: https://firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/

Comment: Gracias @jachguate por la respuesta. El problema es que mi versión de Genexus no contempla la conexión contra Firebird ni Interbase. Estoy buscando un workaround para sortear ese problema, aunque veo difícil solución.

Comment: ¿Soporta conexiones ODBC? https://firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/

Comment: Si, de hecho ya lo he probado, pero resulta que es GeneXus (mi versión (10.3) de GeneXus) la que no soporta Firebird. De ahí que esté buscando algún truco para rodear ese problema.